# Prevent dpkg-build from overriding flags set in CMakeLists.txt during package building

Tags: cmake, debian, deb, dpkg-buildpackage

I am building `deb` package from `c++` project that uses CMake. Package that I build works fine, but binary itself is compiled using various options that override flags set in `CMakeLists.txt`, e.g. flags used for compilation are `-g -O2` instead of `-Os`.

I know that I can override these flags in `debian/rules` files via `DEB_flag_MAINT_opt`, but I don't want to repeate flags from `CMakeLists.txt`, I want them to be defined in single place. Is there some way to prevent `debuild` (this is what I use, it probably uses `dh` or something else under the hood, I can't make heads or tails of Debian's build tools, sorry) from overriding these (and other) flags? While I understand why unification of compile flags is good, I find it absolutely horrendous that it is this hard to prevent flags replacement.